# Update & Return from Stored Procedure withouth Repeating Query

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, view

Having defined a view in SQL Server 2005, I want to write a stored procedures which returns the top *n* elements from this view according to some sorting criteria. However, before returning them I must do some updates to these results, but I can't figure out how to do it without querying the view twice... My solution would be

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateAndReturn

AS

    UPDATE TableToUpdate SET Field = @Something WHERE IDRef IN (SELECT TOP (n) ID FROM View ORDER BY This, That)

    SELECT TOP (n) * FROM View ORDER BY This, That

GO
```

Can anyone help me finding anything more elegant and efficient than this?

Answer (score 2):

Query the view first and put the result to a table variable or a temporary table. Use that table in your update statement and finally do `select *` from the temp table.